# How can i erase a "BMD path" that follows a sprite in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a code like this: https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/ship-trail, there is a moving sprite and a BMD(BitMapData) following it...
How can i clear the BMD path continuously while the sprite advances, like a queue.
I've tried this:

```
var countErase = 0;
var countErase = 0;
var timeToErasePath = 10; //In Seconds

function update()
{
   if(countErase<timeToErasePath*58) //this counts 10 seconds and clear all the BMD path
    {
        bmd.context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
        bmd.context.fillRect(sprite.x, sprite.y, 7 , 7);
        bmd.dirty = true;
        countErase++;
    }
    else{
        countErase = 0;
         bmd.clear();
    }

}
```

But this clear all the path, not only the last points of the BMD path, any idea?

Comment: we are using this to clear all bitmapdata. `bmd.clear();` 
I believe u need to calculate where is your sprite and clear all bitmapdata and fill it again after where u'r sprite is.